# linux cron и БД Oracle

Tags: php, linux, oracle, cron

Добрый день!
Пытаюсь разобраться с запуском скрипта в котором присутствует работа с БД Oracle CRON`ом.
Сам скрипт отрабатывает, если запустить его через браузер. Запуская установив задачу в CRON и выведя ее результат - получил ошибки типа
**Fatal error: Call to undefined function oci_connect**
Проблема в том, что если скрипт отрабатывает через **Apache2** то  все нормально, без участия апача, нет.
Пытался удалить комментарии - безуспешно, перед
;extension=php_oci8.dll
;extension=php_oci8_11.g.dll
На данный момент при отработки скрипта в CRON вообще никакой информации не пишется в файл. Логи CRON в порядке, все выполняется без ошибок.
Не получается побороть эту проблему третий день. Прошу вашего совета!
**Дополнение** :
php -r 'phpinfo();' | grep php.ini

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc/php/7.0/cli
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
```

Значение переменной ORACLE_HOME не пусто
    ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64
Значение LD_LIBRARY_PATH для пользователя root отсутствует.
Для user LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib
Так же есть сложность в том, что в задании CRON уже есть задачи, которые выполняются. Боюсь что изминение глобальной переменной может нарушить их работу.

Comment: посмотрите значение переменной окружения `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` в шелле из которого скрипт работает и обеспечьте такое же значение в задаче запускаемой из cron (например задав переменную глобально в настройках крона или сделав bash скрипт, который ее установит и вызовет php скрипт. Так же будет полезно обеспечить значения всех переменных окружения начинающихся на `ORACLE_`, особенно `ORACLE_HOME`

Comment: @Mike , спасибо за совет, пошел гуглить.

Comment: Бывает, что php.ini отдельный для apache и для крон выполнения. Можно запустить `php -r 'phpinfo();' | grep php.ini` чтобы выяснить, какой php.ini используется для консоли.

Comment: Я думаю, что проблема заключается в разном окружении (ENV) скрипта, когда его запускаете ВЫ и когда его запускает CRON. Это разные пользователи, с разными правами, разными PATH и т.д. Сделайте окружение одинаковым и всё заработает!

Comment: Решил вопрос так: 
в дирректории /etc/profile.d создал oracle.sh с содержанием :  
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib
export ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64
export PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin